# c# how to get hex literal from integer

Tags: c#, string, hex, type-conversion

the are many ways to convert an integer to hex **STRING**, but is there a way to cast it to a hex **literal** as in?

```
string = z
integer = 122
hex = 0X7A
```

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by _hex literal_? What does `string = z` means in the context of your question? [edit] your question and try to make it clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an integer remains an integer irrespective of the representation. You can assign the hex value directly to an `int`. The representation makes only a difference when you want to display it or use it as a string:

```
int integer = 122;
int integer_in_hex = 0X7A;
```

For the display you can use the format string `"X2"`  which means to display the munber in hex with the length of 2 positions:

```
Console.WriteLine(integer_in_hex.ToString("X2"));
Console.WriteLine(integer.ToString("X2"));
```

the output is the same:

> 7A 
>  7A

for more information please read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: so it is only for displaying nothing more and doesn't matter how is it stored in memory as hex takes less space.

Comment: why should hex take less space? an integer can save a number between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647 it has a length of 32 bit. This is the space that it need in memory, irrespective of the representation.

Comment: @bat3a here is more information on int32 please read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @bat3a Hex takes only less space in the context as it needs only 2 characters to represent a 3 digit number. But an integer number of `1` and `1000000000` use the same space in memory. Just for the sake of comparison a `char` is 16-bit long, so using 2 `char`s to represent a 3 digit number amounts to 32-bit, which is the same as int. ;) if you increase your number and the amount of `char`s you will pretty soon exceed the memory that an integer needs :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for string's *dump* (representing characters within the string with their hex values)? Something like this:

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 string test = "hello z";

 // To dump
 string dump = string.Join(" ", test.Select(c => $"0x{(int)c:X2}"));
 // From dump
 string restore = string.Concat(dump
   .Split(' ')
   .Select(item => (char)Convert.ToInt32(item, 16))); 

 Console.WriteLine(dump);
 Console.WriteLine(restore);
```

Outcome

```
 0x68 0x65 0x6C 0x6C 0x6F 0x20 0x7A
 hello z
```